# How to do I set the browser-update script tag to display the name of the browser it is using?

Tags: javascript

I am using browser-update from http://browser-update.org/#install . I am trying to customize the text that user sees to something like. "You are using older version of Internet Explorer...". I can not seem to get the browser name appear on the customized mesage

The javascript code I am using is:

```
var $buoop = {
vs: {i:8,f:35,o:25.63,s:7,c:10},  // browser versions to notify
reminder: 0,                   // atfer how many hours should the message reappear
                                // 0 = show all the time
reminderClosed: 0,             // if the user closes message it reappears after x hours
onshow: function(infos){},      // callback function after the bar has appeared
onclick: function(infos){},     // callback function if bar was clicked
onclose: function(infos){},     //

l: false,                       // set a language for the message, e.g. "en"
                                // overrides the default detection
test: false,                    // true = always show the bar (for testing)
text: "You're using an old version of vs We recommend you <a href='http://browsehappy.com/' target='_new'>upgrade your browser</a> for a better experience using this and other websites. ",                       // custom notification html text
newwindow: true                 // open link in new window/tab
}; 

function $buo_f(){ 
    var e = document.createElement("script"); 
    e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js"; 
  document.body.appendChild(e);

 };

 try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
 catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}
```

Comment: Why would a visitor take any notice of what a random site says about their browser? It's the web, deal with it.

Comment: I will like to show the browser name on the information message. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. One will need to use %s. Apparently it is not on the developer manual, just trial and error I guess. So the code will look like below

```
text: "You're using an old version of %s We recommend you <a href='http://browsehappy.com/' target='_new'>upgrade your browser</a> for a better experience using this and other websites. ",
```